# How can I make Swagger work using an enum of type short?

Tags: c#, enums, asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swashbuckle

I am currently working on a ASP.NET Web API 2 (C#) and have been using Swashbuckle without problems until today. I added a property to an existing model and broke the entire doc generation so whenever I go to **/help/ui/index#!/** page I now see the following:

```
500 : {"message":"An error has occurred."}
```

The enum below is the new property that I added to the existing model. If I remove the `short` type inheritance, everything works fine. Any ideas of how I can use JsonConverter or a custom filter to make sure Swagger doesn't break?

```
public enum TestEnum: short
{
    Unknown = 0,
    Green = 1
}
```

This is the POST request:

```
    [Route("{id:int:min(1)}/customers"), HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult PostCustomer(int id, [FromBody] CustomerModel customerModel)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

It fails when I add a new property to CustomerModel if and only if the Enum is of type short.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: where do you use Enum ? is it get or post and how does route using this model look like?

Comment: It is a post request and it fails only when I add a new property to CustomerModel of TestEnum type.

Comment: Why does it need to be short? Maybe you can solve the problem in some other way, e.g. with a range check.

Comment: the enum is widely used throughout the system so changing type is not feasible. I could create another enum, but it will be an issue later down the road to maintain and keep enums in sync.

Answer (score 0):

I enabled a while back an `IDocumentFilter` that helped us display both integer and string values of an Enum to provide more useful details to our clients.

Issue was that this class was only casting Enums to INTs, so I had to update it to accept other types as well. Here is the class I'm using:

```
public class SwaggerEnumDescriptions : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, IApiExplorer apiExplorer)
    {
        // add enum descriptions to result models
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Schema> schemaDictionaryItem in swaggerDoc.definitions)
        {
            Schema schema = schemaDictionaryItem.Value;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Schema> propertyDictionaryItem in schema.properties)
            {
                Schema property = propertyDictionaryItem.Value;
                IList<object> propertyEnums = property.@enum;
                if (propertyEnums?.Count > 0)
                {
                    property.description += $": {DescribeEnum(propertyEnums)}";
                }
            }
        }

        // add enum descriptions to input parameters
        if (swaggerDoc.paths.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (PathItem pathItem in swaggerDoc.paths.Values)
            {
                DescribeEnumParameters(pathItem.parameters);

                // head, patch, options, delete left out
                List<Operation> possibleParameterisedOperations = new List<Operation> { pathItem.get, pathItem.post, pathItem.put };
                possibleParameterisedOperations.FindAll(x => x != null).ForEach(x => DescribeEnumParameters(x.parameters));
            }
        }
    }

    private void DescribeEnumParameters(IList<Parameter> parameters)
    {
        if (parameters != null)
        {
            foreach (Parameter param in parameters)
            {
                IList<object> paramEnums = param.@enum;
                if (paramEnums?.Count > 0)
                {
                    param.description += $": {DescribeEnum(paramEnums)}";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private string DescribeEnum(IList<object> enums)
    {
        List<string> enumDescriptions = new List<string>();
        foreach (object enumOption in enums)
        {
            Type enumType = enumOption.GetType();
            object enumValue =
                Enum.GetUnderlyingType(enumType) == typeof(byte) ? (byte)enumOption :
                Enum.GetUnderlyingType(enumType) == typeof(short) ? (short)enumOption :
                Enum.GetUnderlyingType(enumType) == typeof(long) ? (long)enumOption :
                (int)enumOption;

            enumDescriptions.Add($"{enumValue} = {Enum.GetName(enumType, enumOption)}");
        }
        return string.Join(", ", enumDescriptions.ToArray());
    }
}
```

In order to use this on your Api, you need to add the IDocumentFilter to Swagger Config:

```
c.DocumentFilter<SwaggerEnumDescriptions>();
```